# How to read the incoming whatsapp messages and respond thru my tool/app

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, web, whatsapp

We are planning to create a customer care application which takes the messages sent to our whatsapp number and respond to them via application. It will be handled with different agents.

The only problem is the way to handle whatsapp messages. This is easier in other messengers. Since Whatsapp doesn't have an official support for business, we need to find a way to do it. I know there are some software with such functionality. How do they do that? Below are some of the application which acts as a customer support using messengers.

https://www.casengo.com/whatsapp-customer-service-and-support-software/

https://ongair.im/

https://orat.io/